# Java AnimationTimer content not showing

Tags: java, animation, javafx

I'm trying to learn how JavaFX animations work, so I've tried to create an animation with Earth moving in a circle, based on this tutorial: https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-javafx-for-game-development--cms-23835.

For some reason, the scene I want to show is set in the stage, but the graphics or animations aren't. I'm pretty sure this one is trivial, I just can't seem to find the reason. Here's my Main class code:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private static Stage stage;
    private static Window window;
    private static Scene scWindow;


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        stage = primaryStage;
        stage.setTitle("Animation");
        showWindow();       
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void showWindow() {
        window = new Window();
        scWindow = new Scene(window, 400, 400);
        stage.setScene(scWindow);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

and this is the Window class code:

```
public class Window extends BorderPane {

    final long startNanoTime = System.nanoTime();
    Image earth = new Image("http://icdn.pro/images/en/g/o/google-earth-icone-8927-128.png");
    Image space = new Image("https://space-facts.com/wp-content/uploads/magellanic-clouds.png");
    GraphicsContext gc;

    public Window() {
        Group root = new Group();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(512, 512);
        gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        root.getChildren().add(canvas);
        gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        Anim a = new Anim();
        a.start();

    }

    private class Anim extends AnimationTimer {
        public void handle(long currentNanoTime)
        {
            double t = (currentNanoTime - startNanoTime) / 1000000000.0; 

            double x = 232 + 128 * Math.cos(t);
            double y = 232 + 128 * Math.sin(t);

            gc.drawImage( space, 0, 0 );
            gc.drawImage( earth, x, y );
        }
    }
}
```

There's no exception thrown or anything, I have no idea what's wrong.

EDIT:
I know that I haven't put anything in the setCenter/Left etc. in the constructor, so actually if it is the reason, how should I put the animation e.g. on the center of the border pane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `root` to the scene. Add something like

```
setCenter(root);
```

to the constructor of `Window`.

Or simply use the `Canvas` as center:

```
public Window() {
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(512, 512);
    gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    setCenter(canvas);
    gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
    Anim a = new Anim();
    a.start();
}
```